# Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location - Laravel S3

Tags: laravel-9

I was using L5.8 for my project, and recently i changed to Laravel 9.
Here after, I'm not able to retrieve the file from Amazon S3, it shows the following error.

> Unable to retrieve the file_size for file at location

This is my code to retrieve the image file

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->response($file_path);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found out, we were using  `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=s3` in previous laravel version.
But for Laravel 9, i've to modify it to `FILESYSTEM_DISK=s3`